# In WPF/C# 2010 how do I make a button disappear if a related data object is null?

Tags: binding

I have a screen that I use to show data from a data table.  The XAML bindings are working and it displays fine.  However, next to one data field, I have a button that I want to use for other things.  My problem is that I don't want the button to show if the data field is null or empty.  Below is snippets of the XAML and data object code that I am using.

XAML for the button:

I am starting out with the button hidden.

Here is the XAML that covers the style "DetailButton":

Here is the data object code that sets PplOlderFlag:

```
        _bOlderFlag = (_sPplOlderInfo.Length > 0);

    public bool PplOlderFlag
    {
        get
        {
            return _bOlderFlag;
        }
    }
```

As I said, the binding (PplOlderInfo) is working and show up fine.  But the button is still there when the PplOlderInfo is null or empty.

I can set the Visibility of button in the code behind easy enough but it just seems like it would be really slick if I could make it work in the XAML.

Any ideas as to what I am leaving out or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: For some reason the XAML didn't show up.  How do I get the XAML to show up in my question description?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the type of PplOlderFlag be of type System.Windows.Visibility?

In my test app, if I make an equivalent property of type System.Windows.Visibility, I can make the button visible or invisible as required.

Edit:

From your code example, I would implement as:

```
public System.Windows.Visibility PplOlderFlag
{
    get
    {
        return _bOlderFlag ? System.Windows.Visibility.Visible : 
                             System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is the XAML for the button: 'code'                            <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="8" Margin="5"
                                    x:Name="btnOlderDetail"
                                    Visibility="Hidden" Style="{StaticResource DetailButton}">
                                <Button.Content>
                                    <Label FontSize="20" Content="Detail"
                                           Foreground="White"/>
                                </Button.Content>
                            </Button>

Comment: The button Visibility is not data bound in your example. You need something like: Visibility="{Binding Path=PplOlderFlag}".  Also have you made sure that the class that contains PplOlderFlag implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged? Have you set the appropriate DataContext?